# Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "MySql.Data, Version=8.0.25.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных, .net, visual-studio

у меня есть .NET Framework приложение, которое использует базу данных на MySQL, и когда я запускаю `exe` файл моего приложения у себя на компьютере то все работает отлично, но когда я этот же `exe` запускаю на стороннем пк, то при запуске получаю вот эту ошибку:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "MySql.Data, Version=8.0.25.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" 
либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.
Имя файла: 'MySql.Data, Version=8.0.25.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'
```

Я так понял эта ошибка говорит о том что у меня стоит не правильная версия `MySql.Data`? я проверял, и у меня в проекте указана та версия которая нужна - `Version=8.0.25.0`, и в GAC указана та же самая версия - `8.0.25.0`... Я уже также пробовал переустанавливать MySql Connector. является ли причиной ошибки то что на стороннем компьютере может быть не установлен MySQL? или все же я у себя в проекте что-то не так сделал? И поможет ли полная переустановка MySql на моем пк? или может, если я буду на сторонний компьютер передавать не только `exe` файл(а до этого момента я делал именно так), а весь проект, то все будет работать? подскажите пожалуйста, заранее - огромное спасибо!

Comment: На другой компьютер вы скидываете только один .exe? Судя по ошибке - да. Нужно скидывать всю папку Release.

Comment: спасибо Вам большое, LiptonDev! Это решило мою проблему! правда теперь при загрузке я получаю эту ошибку: `Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts.`

Comment: Связана ли текущая ошибка с тем что на стороннем пк не установлена платформа .NET?

Comment: или может мне стоит что-то поменять в моем сервере? я использую standard TCP/IP MySql сервер

Comment: Пинг до указанных хостов с клиентской машины есть?

Comment: Здравствуйте, Uranus! в силу моей глупости и не знания я не совсем понял что Вы сказали. На клиентской машине я получаю  такую ошибку: `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.AggregateException: Произошла одна или несколько ошибок. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение 127.0.0.1:3306`

Comment: Вроде в коде все правильно прописываю:`MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=MyPassword;database=ipaddresses;");`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1307773