# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных, .net, visual-studio

Всем здравствуйте! у меня есть .NET Framework приложение, которое использует базу данных на MySQL, и когда я запускаю exe файл моего приложения у себя на компьютере то все работает отлично, но когда я этот же `exe` запускаю на стороннем пк, то при запуске получаю вот эту ошибку:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> 
System.AggregateException: Произошла одна или несколько ошибок. ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение 127.0.0.1:3306
```

если я правильно  понял то проблема в  этих строчках кода:

```
  MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=MyPassword;database=ipaddresses;");

        public void OpenConnection()
        {
           
            if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Open();
        }
```

пробовал менять порядок записи элементов в  переменной `connection` - не  помогает.
Вот как выглядит мой  `MySql` сервер:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
на стороннем пк отсутствуют программы MySql Worbench, Visual Studio, PuTTY. Также на сторонний пк я передаю всю папку Release с моим `exe` файлом.

Я так понял проблема в том что мой сервер распознает сторонний пк как пользователя с которым не следует делится информацией, находящейся в моей базе данных? если так, то есть ли возможность через C# скрипт как-то указать, что к серверу может подключатся не только мой пк, но и сторонние? Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - это IP локального компьютера (localhost), то есть доступ __только__ с этого компьютера. О каком "вашем сервере" может идти речь я не пойму?

Comment: Здравствуйте, EvgeniyZ, спасибо за Ваш комментарий! а что же мне тогда там нужно указать?

Comment: Вам нужно либо создать выделенный сервер где установлен sql (так обычно делают в энтерпрайз-решениях), либо попросить пользователя установить sql себе на машину и поднять сервер. Можно как бы и пользователю дать доступ к вашему компьютеру, но для этого нужно указывать не локальный IP, а IP вашей машины (с кучей дополнительных условий, как-то: находиться в одной подсети, не использовать динамические IP или синхронизировать значения, доступ через NAT, разрешённый firewall и т.п.)

Comment: @HolyWar_ Вы походу не понимаете, как работает интернет. Давайте попробую объяснить. У любого компьютера есть как минимум 2 IP адреса: 1. `127.0.0.1` (`localhost`) -  это локальный адрес, который дает доступ только с этого компьютера. Он отлично подходит для тестов, разработки и так далее, ведь в таких случаях доступ нужен только вам, с этого компьютера. 2. IP, который дает вам ваш провайдер. Его вы можете узнать, например на `2ip.ru`. Но не все так просто, ведь провайдеры хотят кушать и зачастую этот ip постоянно меняется и к нему нет доступа за пределами провайдера, а услуга открытия платная

Comment: @HolyWar_ Если у человека подключение идет через роутер, то у компьютера появляется 3-й IP, тот, что дает ему сам роутер, ведь роутер делает отдельную локальную сеть, в которую входят все устройства, подключенные к нему. И вот у вас на руках 3 IP адреса: `127.0.0.1`, условно `192.168.1.2`, и от провайдера, к примеру `222.222.222.222`. Вы подняли сервер, настраиваете его на первый адрес, что тогда? Правильно, доступ только с вашего компьютера. Настраиваете на 2-й - доступ со всех устройств, что подключены к роутеру. 3 - доступ за пределами вашей сети.

Comment: @HolyWar_ Но не забываем, IP должен быть выделенный (платная услуга провайдера), также не забываем, что роутер по умолчанию берет все запросы на  себя и чтоб был доступ, надо переадресовать порт на ваш компьютер. Ну и также не забываем, что сам сервер, по умолчанию имеет учетную запись, которая доступна __только__ с адреса `127.0.0.1`. Собственно теперь надеюсь вы поняли в чем проблема и поняли что надо прописывать...

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо за столь подробные комментарии и столь подробное объяснение! Действительно, сейчас мне стало более понятно что вообще происходит и как все устроено!